# Copying a sheet to same Excel workbook is giving error - subscript out of range

Tags: vba, excel

Copying a sheet to same Excel workbook is giving error - subscript out of range.

```vb
sub copyWorkSheet()
    Dim myPath As String
    myPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName

    Workbooks("Generator.xlsm").Activate

    Sheets("Details 1").Select
    Sheets("Details 1").Copy After:=Workbooks(myPath).Sheets("Details 2")
End Sub
```

Comment: which line throws the error? .... i am guessing that you do not have `Sheets("Details 1")` or `Sheets("Details 2")`

Comment: Details 1 exists but details 2 doesn’t i was assuming it will create new file as details 2

Comment: `Workbooks(myPath)` will definitely give an error - the index to the `Workbooks` collection should not include a path, so you should have set `myPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Name`

Comment: `i was assuming it will create new file as details 2` .... why would you think that a new file would be created just by referring to a sheet name in the current workbook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of lines where the error may be occurring:

> Workbooks("Generator.xlsm").Activate

Make sure "Generator.xlsm" is open - activate makes 'Generator' the active and available workbook, but will *not* open it for you.

You must also ensure 'Details 1' and 'Details 2' exist in both workbooks, this will also create an error if they do not.

Example corrected code:

```
Sub copyWorkSheet()
    Set otherWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open("Generator.xlsm")
    otherWorkbook.Activate
    otherWorkbook.Sheets("Details 1").Select
    otherWorkbook.Sheets("Details 1").Copy After:=Application.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Details 2")
End Sub
```

This snippet assumes

- You want to copy into 'ThisWorkbook" - the workbook associated with the vba
- Both workbooks contain "Details 1" and "Details 2"
- "Generator.xlsm" will remain open after this code runs.

Comment: details 2 sheet is not created, i was assuming it will create new sheet while on copy?? I am getting error on 7th line.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This looks like a well written answer, nice job.

Comment: @harry, the code will copy "Details 1" to a spot *after* Details 2

Comment: Thanks. I need to rename new file as details 2.. think this will resolve this issue.. let me try and get back..

Comment: Cheers @Airhead. Harry, If there is only one worksheet and you're creating a new one, here is a simpler bit of code:

'Sheets("Details 1").Copy after:=Sheets("Details 1")'
'ActiveSheet.Name = "Details 2"'

Good luck!

Comment: Great!! Awesome help!! It worked perfectly later i made the new file hide by using - ActiveSheet.Visible = xlSheetHidden

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is caused by this line:

```
myPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
```

which returns the name of the object, **including its path on disk**

To address an item within the Workbooks collection you can use its Name property which doesn't include its path.  Changing the above line to:

```
myPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Name
```

will solve your problem provided the `ActiveWorkbook` does contain a sheet named Detail 2.

That said, you should try to avoid using `ActiveWorkbook` because it may not be the workbook that you think it is.  Assuming you want to copy into the workbook where the Sub is saved, it would be safer to refer to `ThisWorkbook.Name`.